# Open-CV memory management in iOS (Objective-c with ARC)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, opencv, automatic-ref-counting

This might be a silly question but does ARC (automatic reference counting) interact with Open CV when programming in the iOS?

I am asking this because I just recently started using Open CV in general. While on iOS with ARC it is not necessary to worry about objects since I only have to make sure to have no pointers pointing at them so that they can be released.

Open CV seems to have a similar cleaning function:

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/memory_management.html

> When using the new interface, the most of memory deallocation and even
>   memory allocation operations are done automatically when needed.

First, does this means I don't have to release those objects?

Second, I am using both OpenCV and Objective C in the same .mm file. Is it safe to assume that the objects won't be messing with each other?

For example this will give me an UIImage from a cv Mat:

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithCVMat:(const cv::Mat&)cvMat
{
    return [[UIImage alloc] initWithCVMat:cvMat];
}
```

Which uses this:

```
- (id)initWithCVMat:(const cv::Mat&)cvMat
{
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:cvMat.data length:cvMat.elemSize() * cvMat.total()];

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;

    if (cvMat.elemSize() == 1)
    {
        colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
    }
    else
    {
        colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    }

    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFDataRef)data);

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(cvMat.cols,                                     // Width
                                        cvMat.rows,                                     // Height
                                        8,                                              // Bits per component
                                        8 * cvMat.elemSize(),                           // Bits per pixel
                                        cvMat.step[0],                                  // Bytes per row
                                        colorSpace,                                     // Colorspace
                                        kCGImageAlphaNone | kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault,  // Bitmap info flags
                                        provider,                                       // CGDataProviderRef
                                        NULL,                                           // Decode
                                        false,                                          // Should interpolate
                                        kCGRenderingIntentDefault);                     // Intent   

    self = [self initWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    return self;
}
```

*method taken from Robin Summerhill

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> First, does this means I don't have to release those objects?

Yes, until you create them using **new** operator. Look at this code:

```
{
cv::Mat image(640,480); // allocate image
//.. do something with it
self.myImage = [UIImage imageWithCVMat:image];
}
// Out of scope - image is deallocated automatically.
// But self.myImage is still accessible since it contains a copy of image.
```

> Second, I am using both OpenCV and Objective C in the same .mm file. Is it safe to assume that the objects won't be messing with each other?

In your **initWithCVMat** functiton the image data is copied to **NSData** object which is used to initialize a new instance of **UIImage**.

For you it means:
1) An instance of UIImage class will be responsible of releasing image data. If you use ARC - it will be done automatically; otherwise you have to call **[UIImage release]**.
2) Don't worry about cv::Mat  - it will release memory automatically when destroyed.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was just very confused since im totally new to opencv, by the way nice work with your webpage, i got a jump start from it long ago. I was going to use the script but i think it broke for ios 5.1.

Comment: Btw i forgot to mention, i think i figured out the reason for the memory crash. It seems that since i am using lucas kanade pyr optical flow method. the pyramid part is moving too many levels when I make abrupt movements, hence using too much memory. MAYBE haha